# Is possible to update google tag manager container in an Android Application without building it again?

Tags: android, google-tag-manager

I'd like to know if is possible to create a method inside my app, which can check if there is a new version of GTM container, if yes, how can I update this file, without rebuild my app?

thanks

Alex

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? Verbose logging indicates that updated containers are downloaded from GTM, but they don't appear to be used.

Comment: I hvaent' been able to successfully have GTM to download a new published container.  if anyone figures this out let me know!

Answer (score 0):

You can force refresh of your default container by calling `ContainerHolder.refresh()`. By default it will be refreshed every 12 hours.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v4/#refresh

Alternatively, as I notice, you can clear your app data, which will force it to redownload the new container if any.

Comment: it downloads the new container vs. just uses the container that was defaulted packaged with the app when you installed?  I can't get mine to refresh. it seems to ALWAYS need to be downloaded from GTM, renamed to "default_container" and put in the raw folder.